# Hyper-V Failover Cluster without domain, possible to use an SMB share on the same cluster?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, server-message-block

We are building a Windows Failover Cluster that will not be on a domain (a necessity), as outlined [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/workgroup-and-multi-domain-clusters-in-windows-server-2016/ba-p/372059). It will ultimately be just a Hyper-V cluster, hosting three Windows Server guests.

The basic setup will be two servers and a SAN connected to both. However, since I'm learning as I go here, I found an article from Microsoft talking about the benefits of using an [SMB share as the storage for a Hyper-V cluster](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj134187(v=ws.11)). This got me thinking, could the SMB share in a setup like that be hosted in the same failover cluster as the Hyper-V role? And would this allow live migration despite the failover cluster not being domain-joined?